# pysnmp.smi.error.SmiError: No symbol error while trying to power on the apc outlet with pysnmp

Tags: python, python-2.7, pysnmp

I am trying to use `pysnmp` module to power on apc outlet.

This is the manual command which works fine:

```
# snmpset -v1 -c comstring 10.x.x.x SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.318.1.1.26.9.2.4.1.5.27 i 1
PowerNet-MIB::rPDU2OutletSwitchedControlCommand.27 = INTEGER: immediateOn(1)
```

Here is the code:

```
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen

cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = cmdGen.setCmd(
    cmdgen.CommunityData('comstring'),
    cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('10.x.x.x', 161)),
    (cmdgen.MibVariable('SNMPv2-SMI', 'enterprises.318.1.1.26.9.2.4.1.5', "27"), 1)
)

# Check for errors and print out results
if errorIndication:
    print(errorIndication)
else:
    if errorStatus:
        print('%s at %s' % (
            errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
            errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex)-1] or '?'
            )
        )
    else:
        for name, val in varBinds:
            print('%s = %s' % (name.prettyPrint(), val.prettyPrint()))
```

I have copied mibs file to following paths:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/mibs
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/mibs/instances
```

I am seeing below error when I try to run the script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snmp3.py", line 128, in <module>
    (cmdgen.MibVariable('SNMPv2-SMI', 'enterprises.318.1.1.26.9.2.4.1.5', "27"), 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/entity/rfc3413/oneliner/cmdgen.py", line 200, in setCmd
    **kwargs):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/hlapi/asyncore/sync/cmdgen.py", line 217, in setCmd
    lookupMib=options.get('lookupMib', True)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/hlapi/asyncore/cmdgen.py", line 239, in setCmd
    contextData.contextName, vbProcessor.makeVarBinds(snmpEngine, varBinds),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/hlapi/varbinds.py", line 39, in makeVarBinds
    __varBinds.append(varBind.resolveWithMib(mibViewController))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/rfc1902.py", line 845, in resolveWithMib
    self.__args[0].resolveWithMib(mibViewController)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/rfc1902.py", line 481, in resolveWithMib
    self.__modName, self.__symName
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/builder.py", line 407, in importSymbols
    'No symbol %s::%s at %s' % (modName, symName, self)
pysnmp.smi.error.SmiError: No symbol SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.318.1.1.26.9.2.4.1.5 at <pysnmp.smi.builder.MibBuilder object at 0x367f550>
```

Can someone please let me know if I am missing anything here? How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess one problem is with wrong `MibVariable` initialization parameters. On top of that, the MIB object you are trying to refer to is not defined in the SNMPv2-SMI MIB.

The `MibVariable` (AKA [ObjectIdentity](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/api-reference.html#mib-variables)) type expects `MIB-name`, `object-name`, `indices`. With your code you pass `object-name` + `indices` glued together as `object-name`. This is why it fails to resolve the MIB object.

How about this:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *
from pysnmp import debug

debug.setLogger(debug.Debug('msgproc'))

snmpEngine = SnmpEngine()

(errorIndication,
 errorStatus,
 errorIndex,
 varBinds) = next(
    setCmd(
      snmpEngine,
      CommunityData('public'),
      UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
      ContextData(),
      ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-SMI', 'enterprises', '318.1.1.26.9.2.4.1.5.27'), Integer32(1))
    )
)
```

Or much better approach would be to actually use the `PowerNet-MIB`:

```
ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('PowerNet-MIB', 'rPDU2OutletSwitchedControlCommand', 27), 1)
```

Or you can just pass that bare OID along with value type to pysnmp:

```
ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.4.1.318.1.1.26.9.2.4.1.5.27'), Integer32(1))
```

Finally, you should not copy your MIBs into pysnmp installation directory. Consider [referring](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/api-reference.html#pysnmp.smi.rfc1902.ObjectIdentity.addAsn1MibSource) to your own MIBs directory instead. Alternatively, you can ask pysnmp to automatically search for and download requested MIBs from [the web](http://mibs.snmplabs.com/asn1).

Comment: I tried it, getting message at the end of the script: `2017-10-27 16:31:23,989 pysnmp: prepareDataElements: SM returned securityEngineId SnmpEngineID() securityName SnmpAdminString('s-9197640422514474689', subtypeSpec=ConstraintsIntersection(ValueSizeConstraint(0, 65535), ValueSizeConstraint(0, 255), ValueSizeConstraint(1, 32)))
2017-10-27 16:31:23,989 pysnmp: prepareDataElements: unique PDU request-id 4735877 replaced with original ID 14896909`, but not seeing actual power on of the outlet happening on apc. anything I am still missing?

Comment: @ Ilya Etingof, I replaced line in my script and it worked like a charm. Thank you so much for this crisp answer!